# Excel Quick Analysis menu. Removing

Tags: excel

Whenever i try to select the bottom right corner of a cell this annoying quick analysis menu comes up. It is shown here in green. This menu prevents me from selecting and incrementing number in a set of cells. Is there a way i can turn this of? So it does come up anymore?

[image: Excel Annoying Quick Analysis Menu]

Answer (score 1):

Go to file, and click options. Then under general, uncheck the option "Show Quick Analysis options on selection".

Comment: No problem, happy to help!